# Is it possible to use two tables from two different databases inside a php function?

Tags: php, database, class, object, pdo

I'm using two databases for my current project. I want to use tables on both database inside a single function. I am calling this function using class object whose constructor function connects single database. How can I connect multiple database at a time?. 
Thanks in Advance.

```
$DB1 = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME1,DB_USER1,DB_PASS1);//(host;dbname,dbuser,dbpass)
$DB1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DB1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);//to avoid quote numeric arguments

$DB2 = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME2,DB_USER2,DB_PASS2);//(host;dbname,dbuser,dbpass)
$DB2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DB2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);//to avoid quote numeric arguments

class Connect{
private $dbh;

//Database Connection
public function __construct($DB_con) {
    $this->dbh = $DB_con;
}

//function to select values from a table
public function select_rows($table,$fieldlist,$condition,$data) {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT $fieldlist FROM $table $condition");
    $stmt->execute($data);
    //$stmt->debugDumpParams(); 
    return $stmt;
}//end function

//function to update values in a table
public function update_rows($table,$fieldlist,$condition,$data) {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE $table set $fieldlist $condition");
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}//end function

//function to update values in a table
public function manage_tables($id1,$id2,$value1,$value2) {
    $cond_db1 = "WHERE ID=?";
    $data_db1 = array($id1);
    $pass_db1 = $this->select_rows('table_from_db1','*',$cond_db1,$data_db1);
    if($pass_db1->rowCount()>0)
    {
        //This section is not working as I called function using object of first db 
        $field_db2    =   "field1=?,field2=?";
        $cond_db2    =   " WHERE cID=? ";
        $data_db2     =   array($value1,$value2,$id2);
        $query_db2    =   $this->update_rows("table_from_db2",$field_db2,$cond_db2,$data_db2);
    }
}//end function
```

}//end class

```
$obj1   = new Connect($DB1);
$obj2   = new Connect($DB2);

$func   =   $obj1->manage_tables($id1,$id2,$value1,$value2);
```

Comment: create only one connection with the user that have access to both db and use database name before the table name eg. `db.table1` and `db2.table2` to use both table in one connection.

Comment: can I get the code? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit what if the Databases are on different servers though (they are not in the example here, but what if)

Comment: @Nichuz You cannot do what you what in this manner, in the obj1 Object you have no knowledge of the second DB connection. The design of your class is wrong, if you build the class independent of the DB connection (as your constructor suggests) you should not use any differentiation based on the DB later in the class methods. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: okay I got it. I took it in the wrong way. Thanks all.